# Airlfow DAG DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator with Google Provided Template GCS_Text_to_Cloud_PubSub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataflow

Basically, I simply want to use the existing Google template [GCS_Text_to_Cloud_PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided/cloud-storage-to-pubsub#console) for using it in my DAG for `DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator`.
I searched a lot but couldn't find a way to download the template and store under my GCS. So that I can point `DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the templates should be under `gs://dataflow-templates/latest`

Comment: Thanks XQ. However, I looked at the cloud storage of my GCP project. And didn't find `datalow-templates` show up. I think something needs to be done to make it available. Otherwise, all GCP project would have this bucket.

Comment: It should be public to all GCP projects. Try `gsutil ls gs://dataflow-templates/latest`